# Grammar, shortening the sentence

Tags: compound-subjects

In the two following sentences is the word "I"  necessary?

> **A**: I usually drive to work, but (I) sometimes walk.
>   **B**: I sometimes walk to work, but (I) not very often.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP was based on a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**A**: In the first sentence, the "**I**" is optional, and its placing can be changed too.

> I usually drive to work, but sometimes walk.
>   I usually drive to work, but I sometimes walk.
>   I usually drive to work, but sometimes I walk.

**B**: In the second sentence, it is wrong, because "**I**" needs a verb. It should be

> I sometimes walk to work, but not very often.

If you want to use another "**I**" it could be like this

> I sometimes walk to work, but I don't walk very often.
>   I sometimes walk to work, but I don't do that very often.
>   I sometimes walk to work, but I usually drive.

Comment: I saw these sentences in a grammar book but now I found that there was a typographical error in the book. Thank you very much.